# Etiquetas de versiones de Android

Tags: discusión, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Me he dado cuenta que existen varias etiquetas refiriéndose a las versiones de Android, las cuales no disponen de muchas preguntas. Estas son:

- [android-jellybean](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-jellybean)
- [android-m](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-m)
- [android-n](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-n)

y me he preguntado sino sería mejor englobarlas directamente en la etiqueta [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) ya que en la descripción de la etiqueta se enumeran todas las versiones de Android e incluso se ponen los enlaces de referencia a las Apis de cada versión.

Sugiero que estas etiquetas hagan referencia a la etiqueta [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).

Comment: ¿Por qué hacer sinónimos y no editar el wiki de [tag:android] para promover el uso de las etiquetas que corresponden a las versiones?

Comment: @Rubén ¿y tener etiquetas para un par de preguntas solamente?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Habría que ver cada caso individual. En cuanto a las etiquetas de versiones de lenguaje no le veo problema alguno. ¿Tu sí?

Comment: Y bueno, comencemos a crear etiquetas para las herramientas de Google desde que estaban en Beta, y también para todas las versiones de los LPs, y tb para los frameworks, y así inundémonos de etiquetas que pueden tener 1 o 2 preguntas solamente, pero el sitio estaría *mejor*. Si bien debemos revisar cada caso, parece que no has revisado **este** caso que plantea Joacer. Las etiquetas en cuestión tienen 2, 2 y 1 preguntas, respectivamente. A eso yo pregunto: ¿realmente vale la pena tener estas etiquetas? ¿conviene ser tan específico? ¿en serio?

Comment: En SO en inglés por ejemplo si que tienen sentido estás etiquetas porqué tienen unas 200 o más preguntas por etiqueta, se que es una buena forma de organizar las preguntas y de poder filtrar más fácilmente, pero en este caso de momento no llevan esa progresión de crecimiento y sino me equivoco acabarán desapareciendo

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Claro que ví los casos de las tres etiquetas de versión, y por eso mencioné que no le veo problema. Te lo planteo de otra forma ¿realmente vale la pena hacer sinónimos de una etiqueta más general siendo que las preguntas con esas etiquetas ya la incluyen? ¿Que tal si luego surgen mas preguntas que sean sobre cuestiones específicas sobre la versión?

Comment: @Rubén buen punto. [Esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/68317/83) es específica de una versión: _Para obtener ... del bluetooth, en versiones anteriores a Android M uso..._. Yo voto en contra de crear sinónimos. Valoraría cómo puede evolucionar el tema y probablemente dejarías las etiquetas si se detecta un uso moderado de ellas (las últimas versiones seguramente vayan a tener más casos, pues cada vez tenemos más preguntas). Otra cosa es que los nombres actuales son poco descriptivos. _Android 7_ o _Android Nougat_ serían más fácilmente distinguibles que una mera _m_ o _n_.

Comment: @Joacer: Las etiquetas con más de seis meses de antigüedad, que **sólo tienen una pregunta** son eliminadas de forma automática, no así las que tienen dos o más preguntas. Entonces, si la etiqueta sería eliminada de forma automática, ¿vale la pena hacerla sinónimo de una etiqueta más general?

Comment: Igual no vale la pena hacer sinónimos sino hacer una revisión de las preguntas de Android clasificando las por versiones si es posible y así darle un uso y mejorar el filtrado de estas preguntas. Cuando disponga algo más de tiempo intentaré organizar esto

Comment: @Rubén hablemos de hechos más que de supuestos. Sinceramente, una etiqueta para solo 2 preguntas y que ha pasado más de un año sin recibir nuevas preguntas, me hace ruido.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Eres rudo. Tiras una "golpe" como el de " y bueno, comencemos a crear etiquetas..." y luego sales con " hablemos de hechos mas que de supuestos". Dejando eso de lado, ¿podrías explicar con hechos, como tu sugieres, los efectos de tener las etiquetas en cuestión con dos preguntas?

Comment: @Rubén lo repito: "una etiqueta para solo 2 preguntas y que ha pasado más de un año sin recibir nuevas preguntas, me hace ruido"

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Ese es un hecho. Otro hecho es que a mí no me hace ruido.

Answer (score 2):

> Lo coloco aquí por la extensión y formato como el insertado automático del título de las preguntas.

En relación al [comentario del OP](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2501/etiquetas-de-versiones-de-android#comment7777_2501) sobre hacer una revisión de las preguntas de Android clasificando por versiones, he realizado búsquedas usando términos como marshmellow, nougat.

Recién encontré lo siguiente:

- [Resources NotFoundException al intentar inflar un layout](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/64575/65)

  - Esta pregunta menciona un mensaje de error que ocurre en Android M (marshmallow) y Android J (jellybean). No tiene etiquetas de versión. ¿Valdrá la pena agregarlas?
- [Captura de video Android Studio (Android Nougat)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75252/65)

  - Esta pregunta menciona que el problema sobre el cual se consulta se presenta en Android N (Nougat). No tiene comentarios, votos ni respuestas y sólo tenía [android-studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) por lo que agregué [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) y [android-n](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-n) con la finalidad de darle mayor visibilidad, al menos por la etiqueta android, y el ser "reflotada"<sup>1</sup>.

Considero bastante posible que existan más preguntas a las que he habría que agregar las etiquetas de versión mencionadas en la pregunta.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Lo de agregar la etiqueta de versión fue para aprovechar la edición, no por otra cosa. Reconozco que esto ahora hace que la etiqueta de versión tenga dos preguntas y con ello no sería eliminada de forma automática.

Comment: @Jorgesys Gracias por la corrección. Cabe hacer notar que la pregunta referida dice  `marshmellow` en lugar `marshmallow` :D

Comment: He visto lo que indicas, ya edité la pregunta. En cuanto al mensaje de  error, el usuario indica que sucede en Marshmallow, pero es un error que puede ocurrir en cualquier sistema operativo.

Answer (score 1):

Consideremos el significado de etiqueta (obtenido de https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags):

> Una etiqueta es una palabra clave o un rótulo que categoriza tu pregunta con otras preguntas similares. El uso de las etiquetas correctas facilita que otros encuentren tu pregunta y la respondan.

Bajo este concepto y basado en que una etiqueta que tiene solo 2 preguntas y no ha recibido más publicaciones en el año es ser muy detallista. Lo que sí, creo que debe evaluarse cada caso de manera puntual para saber si la versión de un lenguaje o tecnología realmente es tan importante como para que se convierta en una etiqueta (como siempre, apuntando a la definición de etiqueta en el sitio).

En mi opinión, las etiquetas mencionadas por Joacer deberían convertirse en un sinónimo, o bien ser eliminadas.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo. Poco sentido tiene etiquetar versiones incrementales de un lenguaje, biblioteca o similar. Sí está justificado cuando la versión constituye un cambio radical, como es el caso de [tag:angularjs] y [tag:angularjs-2.0]; lo cual también se nota en los números, 876 y 212 preguntas respectivamente.

Comment: Yo también lo veo de esa forma. Etiquetas tan específicas de versiones, salvo casos excepcionales, me parece que sobran. Más aún si su uso es anecdótico

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con la idea general de tu planteo, pero no tanto para etiquetas de versiones, ya que muchas veces ayudan a búsquedas de preguntas específicas. Estás mencionando que sólo recibieron 2 preguntas, pero hay que considerar que [tag:android-m] y [tag:android-n] sólo llevan 2 meses de vida. Personalmente, en este caso, las dejaría vivir un tiempo y volver a evaluar más adelante.

Answer (score 1):

Estoy de acuerdo.

Las etiquetas que indicas en realidad son versiones las cuales sin duda deben ser sinónimos de [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) :

- [android-jellybean](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-jellybean)
- [android-m](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-m)
- [android-n](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-n)

Si revisamos el sitio en inglés se puede encontrar por ejemplo etiquetas de versiones de sistema operativo android, como son:

- [android-froyo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-froyo)

[ver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-2.2-froyo)

[android-honeycomb](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-honeycomb)

[ver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-3.0-honeycomb)

[android-jellybean](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-jellybean)

[ver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-4.2-jelly-bean)

[android-marshmallow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-marshmallow)

[ver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-6.0-marshmallow)

Como comentas, sería importante agregar estos tags como sinónimos de [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) para **evitar fragmentación innecesaria de la etiqueta [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)**.

Dentro del cuerpo de la pregunta o en el titulo pueden agregar como dato la versión del sistema operativo.

**Otra opción es definir las etiquetas padres para contener las versiones, por ejemplo:**

[android-marshmallow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-marshmallow) contendría:

[android-m](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-m), [android-6.0-marshmallow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-6.0-marshmallow), [android-6.0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-6.0), [android-6.0.1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-6.0.1), etc...

Comment: ¿Tu argumento es que lo que sucede en SOen complica las cosas/está mal y que en SOes debe ser diferente?

Comment: No me parece que sea incorrecto en SOen, simplemente así se dio porque los usuarios empezaron agregar las etiquetas, de hecho anteriormente la fragmentación era aun mayor, además de android-m, se tenía android-6.0-marshmallow, android-6.0, android-m, android-6.0.1 etc. Actualicé mi respuesta.

Comment: Salvo que estás de acuerdo, lo demás me parece confuso si apoya o refuta con lo que estás de acuerdo :)

Comment: Creo que nadie conoce la etiqueta [tag:android] mejor que vos, Jorgesys, por lo que respeto totalmente tu opinión en esto. Pero me pasa lo mismo que a @Rubén. Lo que no entiendo es, si en SOen existen (y no son sinónimos), ¿no nos convendría aprender del caso de allá? Es decir, ¿qué ganaríamos si no existieran estas etiquetas de versiones?

Answer (score 1):

Lo dejo como está ahora.

Rechazo la idea de hacer sinónimos y también rechazo eliminar las etiquetas. Hay que esperar a que la etiqueta se elimine automáticamente, y en ese caso, volver a pensar cómo etiquetar esas preguntas.